# Servlet Container (e.g.Tomcat) vs. NIO framework (e.g. Grizzly) For RESTful applications?

Tags: java, rest, nio, web-application-design, servlet-container

What is the pros and cons of using **Servlet Containers** (like `Apache Tomcat`) in contrast with using **NIO frameworks** (such as `Netty` and `Grizzly`) for hosting a JAX-RS RESTful service?

I'm going to develop a RESTful application using Java. Java has **JAX-RS API** (JSR [331](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311) and JSR [339](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339)) for building RESTful services. There is different implementation for it as you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services#Implementations). All of them implement JAX-RS API and so it should be easy (at least in theory) to switch between them. `Jersey` is the reference implementation and I chose it for now.

For the client part I'm going to use `angularJS`+`bootstrap` (so just html/css/js and no jsp pages).

*Just for the record I say that I use `PostgreSQL` as my DB and `EclipseLink` as my JPA (ORM).*

Here I think I just miss one part and that's the server part (the host for JAX-RS service). AFAIK I can either use a Servlet Container (e.g. `Apache tomcat`) or a customize server (using NIO framwroks such as `Netty` and `Grizzly`, or maybe [NIO.2](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=203) which is [part of JDK 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O#JDK_7_and_NIO.2)) for that purpose.

But I don't know which one should I use. I think a pros and cons between this two solution help me choose one.

Comment: Well, what is your aim?

Comment: @AdamArold What should I answer you bro? I want to develop a web application usnign JAX-RS as I said above. I don't have any restriction for now. But later I want to separate my projects as different independent services. I like to design it in SOA way but for now I don't know what should I do. I think RESTful design help to design a SOA app.

Comment: Use the one you know better, and will be easier for you to support in long term. If for learning, then use both in 2 distinctive implementations.